# ProcessPoolExecutor on shared dataset and multiple arguments

Tags: python, multiprocessing, process-pool

I am facing an issue I was not able to solve by doing some search on the web.

I am using the minimal code below. The goal is to run some function 'f_sum' several million times by multiprocessing (using the ProcessPoolExecutor). I am adding multiple arguments by a list of tuples 'args'. In addition, the function is supposed to use some sort of data which is the same for all executions (in the example it's just one number). I do not want to add the data to the 'args' tuple for memory reasons.

The only option I found so far is adding the data outside of the "if **name** == '**main**'". This will (for some reason that I do not understand) make the variable available to all processes. However, updating is not possible. Also, I do not really want to make the data definition outside because in the actual code it will be based on data import and might require additional manipulation.

Hope you can help and thanks in advance!

PS: I am using Python 3.7.9 on Win 10.

```
from concurrent.futures import ProcessPoolExecutor
import numpy as np

data = 0 # supposed to be a large data set & shared among all calculations)
num_workers = 6  # number of CPU cores
num_iterations = 10  # supposed to be large number


def f_sum(args):
    (x,y) = args
    print('This is process', x, 'with exponent:', y)
    value = 0
    for i in range(10**y):
        value += i
    return value/10**y + data


def multiprocessing(func, args, workers):
    with ProcessPoolExecutor(workers) as executor:
        results = executor.map(func, args)
    return list(results)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    data = 0.5  # try to update data, should not be part of 'args' due to memory

    args = []
    for k in range(num_iterations):
        args.append((k, np.random.randint(1,8)))

    result = multiprocessing(f_sum, args, num_workers)

    if np.abs(result[0]-np.round(result[0])) > 0:
        print('data NOT updated')
```

Edit to original question:

**>> Performance Example 1**

```
from concurrent.futures import ProcessPoolExecutor
import numpy as np
import time

data_size = 10**8
num_workers = 4
num_sum = 10**7
num_iterations = 100
data = np.random.randint(0,100,size=data_size)
# data = np.linspace(0,data_size,data_size+1, dtype=np.uintc)

def f_sum(args):
    (x,y) = args
    print('This is process', x, 'random number:', y, 'last data', data[-1])
    value = 0
    for i in range(num_sum):
        value += i
    result = value - num_sum*(num_sum-1)/2 + data[-1]
    return result

def multiprocessing(func, args, workers):
    with ProcessPoolExecutor(workers) as executor:
        results = executor.map(func, args)
    return list(results)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    t0 = time.time()

    args = []
    for k in range(num_iterations):
        args.append((k, np.random.randint(1,10)))

    result = multiprocessing(f_sum, args, num_workers)

    print(f'expected result: {data[-1]}, actual result: {np.unique(result)}')
    t1 = time.time()
    print(f'total time: {t1-t0}')
```

**>> Output**

```
This is process 99 random number: 6 last data 9
expected result: 86, actual result: [ 3.  9. 29. 58.]
total time: 11.760863542556763
```

Leads to false result if randint is used. For linspace result is correct.

**>> Performance Example 2 - based on proposal in answer**

```
from concurrent.futures import ProcessPoolExecutor
import numpy as np
from multiprocessing import Array
import time

data_size = 10**8
num_workers = 4
num_sum = 10**7
num_iterations = 100
input = np.random.randint(0, 100, size=data_size)
# input = np.linspace(0, data_size, data_size + 1, dtype=np.uintc)

def f_sum(args):
    (x,y) = args
    print('This is process', x, 'random number:', y, 'last data', data[-1])
    value = 0
    for i in range(num_sum):
        value += i
    result = value - num_sum*(num_sum-1)/2 + data[-1]
    return result

def init_pool(the_data):
    global data
    data = the_data

def multiprocessing(func, args, workers, input):
    data = Array('i', input, lock=False)
    with ProcessPoolExecutor(max_workers=workers, initializer=init_pool, initargs=(data,)) as executor:
        results = list(executor.map(func, args))
    return results

if __name__ == '__main__':
    t0 = time.time()
    args = []
    for k in range(num_iterations):
        args.append((k, np.random.randint(1,10)))

    result = multiprocessing(f_sum, args, num_workers, input)

    print(f'expected result: {input[-1]}, actual result:{np.unique(result)}')
    t1 = time.time()
    print(f'total time: {t1-t0}')
```

**>> Output**

```
This is process 99 random number: 7 last data 29
expected result: 29, actual result: [29.]
total time: 30.8266122341156
```

@Booboo

I added two examples to my original question, the "Performance Example 2" is based on your code. First interesting finding, my original code actually gives incorrect results if the data array is initialized with random integers. I noticed, that each process by itself initializes the data array. Since it is based on random numbers each process uses a different array for calculation, and even different than the main. So that use case would not work with this code, in your code it is correct all the time.

If using linspace, however, it works, since this gives the same result each time. Same would be true for the use case where some data is read from a file (which is my actual use case). Example 1 is still about 3x faster than Example 2, and I think the time is mainly used by the initializing of the array in your method.

Regarding memory usage I don't see a relevant difference in my task manager. Both Example produce a similar increase in memory, even if the shape is different.

I still believe that your method is the correct approach, however, memory usage seems to be similar and speed is slower in the example above.

Comment: Did the answer I posted answer your question to your satisfaction?

Comment: Any code placed outside of `if \_\_name\_\_ == '\_\_main\_\_': is executed by all sub-processes so any data initialized by such code are available to each worker. *But the data  exist as separate copies in separate memory spaces and are not sharable.*

Comment: Since each process is initializing its copy of data with *random* data, each process in the process pool is working with a *different version of `data` and that is why Example 1 produces the results you see.*.

Comment: Thanks again for clarifying highly appreciate it. This leaves one thing I don't understand: Why is the required memory not ~4x higher with Example 1. After all, it was the original goal to have the data shared to save memory. Not sure if the task manager is an accurate indicator though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most efficient used of memory would be to use shared memory so that all processes are working on the same instance of `data`. This would be absolutely necessary if the processes updated `data`. In the example below, since the access to `data` is read only and I am using a simple array of integers, I am using `multiprocessing.Array` with no locking specified. The "trick" is to initialize your pool by specifying the `initializer` and `initargs` arguments so that each process in the pool has access to this shared memory. I have made a couple of other changes to the code, which I have commented

```
from concurrent.futures import ProcessPoolExecutor
import numpy as np
from multiprocessing import Array, cpu_count # new imports


def init_pool(the_data):
    global data
    data = the_data

def f_sum(args):
    (x,y) = args
    print('This is process', x, 'with exponent:', y)
    value = 0
    for i in range(10**y):
        value += i
    return value/10**y + len(data) # just use the length of data for now

def multiprocessing(func, args, workers):
    data = Array('i', range(1000), lock=False) # read-only, integers 0, 1, 2, ... 999
    with ProcessPoolExecutor(max_workers=workers, initializer=init_pool, initargs=(data,)) as executor:
        results = list(executor.map(func, args)) # create the list of results here
    print(results) # so that it can be printed out for demo purposes
    return results


if __name__ == '__main__':
    num_iterations = 10  # supposed to be large number
    #num_workers = 6  # number of CPU cores
    num_workers = cpu_count()  # number of CPU cores

    args = []
    for k in range(num_iterations):
        args.append((k, np.random.randint(1,8)))

    result = multiprocessing(f_sum, args, num_workers)

    if np.abs(result[0]-np.round(result[0])) > 0:
        print('data NOT updated')
```

Prints:

```
This is process 0 with exponent: 2
This is process 1 with exponent: 1
This is process 2 with exponent: 4
This is process 3 with exponent: 3
This is process 4 with exponent: 5
This is process 5 with exponent: 1
This is process 6 with exponent: 5
This is process 7 with exponent: 2
This is process 8 with exponent: 6
This is process 9 with exponent: 6
[1049.5, 1004.5, 5999.5, 1499.5, 50999.5, 1004.5, 50999.5, 1049.5, 500999.5, 500999.5]
data NOT updated
```

**Updated Example 2**

You saw my comments to your question concerning Example 1.

Your Example 2 is still not ideal: You have the statement `input = np.random.randint(0, 100, size=data_size)` as a global being needlessly executed by every process as it is initialized for use in the process pool. Below is an updated solution that also shows one way how you can have your worker function work directly with a `numpy` array that is backed up a `multiprocessing.Array` instance so that the `numpy` array exists in shared memory. You don't have to use this technique for what you are doing since you are only using `numpy` to create random numbers (I an not sure why), but it is a useful technique to know. But you should re-rerun your code after moving the initialization code of `input` as I have so it is only executed once.

I don't have the occasion to work with `numpy` day to day but I have come to learn that it uses multiprocessing internally for many of its own functions. So it is often not the best match for use with multiprocessing, although that does not seem to be applicable here since even in the case below we are just indexing an element of an array and it would not be using a sub-process to accomplish that.

```py
from concurrent.futures import ProcessPoolExecutor
import numpy as np
from multiprocessing import Array
import time
import ctypes

data_size = 10**8
num_workers = 4
num_sum = 10**7
num_iterations = 100
# input = np.linspace(0, data_size, data_size + 1, dtype=np.uintc)


def to_shared_array(arr, ctype):
    shared_array = Array(ctype, arr.size, lock=False)
    temp = np.frombuffer(shared_array, dtype=arr.dtype)
    temp[:] = arr.flatten(order='C')
    return shared_array

def to_numpy_array(shared_array, shape):
    '''Create a numpy array backed by a shared memory Array.'''
    arr = np.ctypeslib.as_array(shared_array)
    return arr.reshape(shape)

def f_sum(args):
    (x,y) = args
    print('This is process', x, 'random number:', y, 'last data', data[-1])
    value = 0
    for i in range(num_sum):
        value += i
    result = value - num_sum*(num_sum-1)/2 + data[-1]
    return result

def init_pool(shared_array, shape):
    global data
    data = to_numpy_array(shared_array, shape)

def multiprocessing(func, args, workers, input):
    input = np.random.randint(0, 100, size=data_size)
    shape = input.shape
    shared_array = to_shared_array(input, ctypes.c_long)
    with ProcessPoolExecutor(max_workers=workers, initializer=init_pool, initargs=(shared_array, shape)) as executor:
        results = list(executor.map(func, args))
    return input, results

if __name__ == '__main__':
    t0 = time.time()
    args = []
    for k in range(num_iterations):
        args.append((k, np.random.randint(1,10)))

    input, result = multiprocessing(f_sum, args, num_workers, input)

    print(f'expected result: {input[-1]}, actual result:{np.unique(result)}')
    t1 = time.time()
    print(f'total time: {t1-t0}')
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your effort. I tried to put the code into some stress test by using "np.random.randint(0,100,size=10**8)" instead of the range above. Using 4 workers and 40 iterations I end up with about 25s, while the original code is at about 5s. Also, with your code my memory seems to spike much more. 

The weird thing is, that it seems to take quite some time to initialize everything, since the first print is quite delayed.

Comment: In your program you have `data = 0`. That is hardly "large data". What are you doing that is comparable to passing to your worker function a large data array?

Comment: Edited original question and added comment at the end.

Comment: Wow, love it. Its faster than all codes before and more memory efficient from what I can tell with the task manager. Can't say I understand everything that is going on, but it works like a charm. Very nice, thanks.